# Windows 10 L2TP VPN connection issue

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, firewall, l2tp

I have a Windows 10 client which has been configured to connect to an L2TP VPN.

**To get the connection to work**, I had to add the `"AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule"` registry Key, and then totally disable Windows Firewall—the VPN connects perfectly this way.

However, **I cannot** get the VPN to connect with the **Windows Firewall enabled** and I really need to keep the Windows Firewall enabled and be able to connect to the L2TP VPN.

I have also allowed...

- Protocol `50` (ESP) in and out
- UDP `1701`, `4500`, `500` in and out

However the VPN still only connects if I totally disable the Windows Firewall and not with it enabled.

**Question:** Any help or guidance suggested to further troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: AFAIK the UDP ports you need for L2TP are 1701, 4500 and 500. Not 5000.

Comment: I will try that and let you know to post the answer if it works thanks @Pimp

Comment: Try to enable IP Protocol ID 51 for Authentication Header (AH) traffic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Trouble getting Windows to connect to an L2TP VPN

1. Firstly, if the VPN server is behind a [NAT](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/nat-firewall/) and the VPN client is behind a [NAT](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/nat-firewall/) this could cause a problem because apparently ["by default Windows does not support IPSec network address translation (NAT) Traversal (NAT-T) security associations to servers that are located behind a NAT device"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926179/how-to-configure-an-l2tp-ipsec-server-behind-a-nat-t-device-in-windows), and this applies to Windows 10 still as well.

   The advice given by Microsoft ["if you have to put a server behind a NAT device and then use an IPsec NAT-T environment, you can enable communication by changing a registry value on the ***VPN client computer and the VPN server***."](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926179/how-to-configure-an-l2tp-ipsec-server-behind-a-nat-t-device-in-windows)

### PowerShell (Suggested Fix)

**Note:** *You must run this in an admin elevated PowerShell session.*

```
## -- Add registry key to support for L2TP communications via double NAT
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent" -Name "AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule" -Type DWORD -Value 2 –Force;
```

**Important:** *You must restart the machine(s) you apply this to before it's effective.*

> Create and configure the **`AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule`** registry key with a `2` value beneath **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent`** registry subkey and define it as a `DWORD` value.
>
> ---
>
> - A value of `2` configures Windows so that it can establish security associations when both the Windows Server and Windows VPN client computer are behind NAT devices.
>
> [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926179/how-to-configure-an-l2tp-ipsec-server-behind-a-nat-t-device-in-windows)

### PowerShell (Remove Fix)

**Note:** *You must run this in an admin elevated PowerShell session.*

```
## -- Remove registry key for L2TP communications support via double NAT
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent" -Name "AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule" –Force;
```

**Important:** *You must restart the machine(s) you apply this to before it's effective.*

---

### If it is not a double NAT issue then . . .

2. <strike>It seems perhaps in some configurations port `1701` is used over TCP and UDP both and not just UDP only. Adjust your rule to allow the TCP port `1701` through as well and see if that fixes the problem.</strike>

> <strike>**Layer Two Tunneling Protocol (L2TP)** uses TCP port 1701 and is an extension of the Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol. L2TP is often used
> with IPSec to establish a Virtual Private Network (VPN).</strike>
>
> **2020-06-25: Fixed typo, that L2TP uses UDP, not TCP**
>
> [Source](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB5671&actp=METADATA)

3. Furthermore, ensure your Windows Firewall "allow" rule(s) for the ***applicable TCP and UDP ports*** (and ***any correlated VPN client software exe's***, etc.) from the `Advanced` tab has all `private`, `domain`, and `public` profiles checked.

[image]

4. Upon further research it's not super clear to me if some of this applies to the client side rather than the VPN server side for L2TP but some advice suggests actually allowing UDP port `50`.
5. There's another post that also talks about the [`ESP (value 50)   <- Used by IPSec data path`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rrasblog/2006/06/14/which-ports-to-unblock-for-vpn-traffic-to-pass-through/) and others that refer to the ports used by IPSec protocols and ports.

- > **Remember,** I'm not certain if #4 and #5 both apply to the connecting client side but something to consider investigating further and opening up additional access for correlated protocols and/or ports.

### Further Troubleshooting

To troubleshoot further, consider running [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) with the Windows Firewall disabled and make the successfully VPN connection and save that trace. Then with the Windows Firewall enabled, run a new trace, attempt a VPN connection, and save that trace.

Now you can look over both successful and unsuccessful L2TP VPN connection traces, filter, and see at the packet level what is really going on to determine what further you may need to allow through the Windows Firewall.

---

### Supporting Resources

- [How to configure an L2TP/IPsec server behind a NAT-T device in Windows and in Windows Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/926179/how-to-configure-an-l2tp-ipsec-server-behind-a-nat-t-device-in-windows)
- [Windows 10 L2TP/IPsec Manual Setup Instructions](https://www.giganews.com/support/vyprvpn/vpn-setup/windows-10/l2tp.html)
- [What is a NAT firewall and how does it work?](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/nat-firewall/)
- [Set-ItemProperty](https://ss64.com/ps/set-itemproperty.html)
- [Remove-ItemProperty](https://ss64.com/ps/remove-itemproperty.html)
- [L2TP Ports](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d05024ff-d6e7-49a8-8e73-132830dc7924/l2tp-ports?forum=winserverNIS)
- [Understanding Firewall Profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd448531(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_2_Tunneling_Protocol)

Comment: For the effort and completeness of this answer you get the bounty. Thank you

Comment: The source for point 2 has changed their page to say that 1701 is UDP only - it no longer mentions 1701 over TCP. Thanks for the registry fix!

Comment: `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow Outbound L2TP"  -Direction Outbound -LocalPort 500,1701,4500 -Protocol UDP -Action Allow -Profile Domain,Private,Public`  and  `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow Inbound L2TP"  -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 500,1701,4500 -Protocol UDP -Action Allow -Profile Domain,Private,Public`

Answer (score 0):

You've configured the wrong ports in your Windows firewall.

For L2TP you need UDP ports 500, 1701 and 4500.

Port 5000 is incorrect (if that was not a typo).

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing **IP Protocol ID 51**, used for Authentication Header (AH) traffic.

From
[IBM Layer 2 Tunnel Protocol](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzaja/rzajal2tpprotocol.htm):

> L2TP is actually a variation of an IP encapsulation protocol. The L2TP tunnel is created by encapsulating an L2TP frame inside a User Datagram Protocol (UDP) packet, which in turn is encapsulated inside an IP packet. The source and destination addresses of this IP packet define the endpoints of the connection. Because the outer encapsulating protocol is IP, you can apply IPSec protocols to the composite IP packet. This protects the data that flows within the L2TP tunnel. You can then apply **Authentication Header (AH)**, Encapsulated Security Payload (ESP), and the Internet Key Exchange (IKE) protocol in a straightforward way.

[Wikipedia IPSEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec):

> Authentication Headers (AH) provides connectionless data integrity and data origin authentication for IP datagrams and provides protection against replay attacks.

Answer (score 0):

DNS (port 53 [and 853 over TLS])?

Assuming you know reasonably well what you are doing and have already ticked off all the listed required ports, I would guess you are getting plunked by DNS queries. This is the one that was getting me. I was using hostnames not IPs, so it kept trying to do a DNS lookup first (through a firewall that was blocking them).